# Powershell script to get data from json file

Tags: json, powershell

I need to pull data with a particular heading from a json file and output it to a csv file

```
$data = (Get-Content "C:\Users\QVL6\Downloads\express-ordering-web- 
variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

## get data

```
 [PSCustomObject[]]$data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Name'
    Type = 'Type'
    Value = 'Value'
    Description = 'Description'
}
```

)

```
$path = C:\Users\QVL6\
$data | Select-Object -Property Name, Type, Value, Description | Export -Csv 
-Path .\data.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Json file:

```
  {
  "Id": "variableset-Projects-174",
  "OwnerId": "Projects-174",
  "Version": 23,
  "Variables": [
    {
      "Id": "dfd06d9f-5ab5-0b40-bfed-d11cd0d90e62",
      "Name": "apiConfig:orderCommandUrl",
      "Value": "http://dev.order-service.local",
      "Description": null,
      "Scope": {
        "Environment": [
          "Environments-63"
        ]
      },
      "IsEditable": true,
      "Prompt": null,
      "Type": "String",
      "IsSensitive": false
    },
    {
      "Id": "252a19a0-4650-4920-7e66-39a80c1c49ec",
      "Name": "apiConfig:orderCommandUrl",
      "Value": "http://qa.order-service.local",
      "Description": null,
      "Scope": {
        "Environment": [
          "Environments-63",
          "Environments-64"
        ]
      },
      "IsEditable": true,
      "Prompt": null,
      "Type": "String",
      "IsSensitive": false
    },
```

I want to pull out all the values in Name field

Comment: Why are you piping the result of `Get-Content` to `Out-String` instead of directly to `ConvertFrom-JSON`?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58505135/edit) your question to explain exactly what you are trying to do, with examples of the data that you are reading and that you expect to write. As it is, your question is not clear about what you are trying to accomplish, and we cannot help you without further clarification.

Comment: Ok but how do I get it to print out the fields to a csv file or even just the console

Comment: The following info at Microsoft Docs may be of interest: [`ConvertFrom-JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6), [`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6), [`ConvertTo-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6), [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) ...

Comment: ... and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)

Comment: If I have a json file saved in a location, how do I search through it and output the values for a field named "Name"

Comment: Sorry but I am new to Powershell and json

Comment: Perhaps best if you would show us (part of) the json file and show us youyr desired CSV output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Content` already returns a string so you could convert the output directly to json.
    $data = Get-Content "C:\Users\myFile\Downloads\express-ordering-web-variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

The variable `$data` is already an object so you don't have to convert it again to a csv. You can directly select the needed headers and export them to a csv.

```
$data = Get-Content "C:\Users\myFile\Downloads\express-ordering-web- 
variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

#get some random data
[PSCustomObject[]]$data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        H1 = 'Test'
        H2 = 'Test2'
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        H1 = 'Test'
        H2 = 'Test2'
    }
)

$data | Select-Object -Property H1, H2 | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That just produces headers in the csv file. I need to search through the file and pick out and field value in "Name" field. How do I populate those values under the header of Name.

Comment: could you show us the content of `$data` after `$data = Get-Content "C:\Users\myFile\Downloads\express-ordering-web- 
variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json`?

Comment: $data = Get-Content "C:\Users\QVL6\Downloads\express-ordering-web- 
   variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

    #get some random data

    [PSCustomObject[]]$data = @(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            H1 = 'Name'
            H2 = 'Type'
            H3 = 'Value'
            H4 = 'Description'
        }
    )

    $path = C:\Users\QVL6\Documents\Temp\
    $data | Select-Object -Property H1, H2, H3, H4 | Export-Csv -Path .\data.csv - 
   NoClobber -NoTypeInformation

Comment: well, you have to remove the `#get some random data` because you have your own data inside `$data` and you have to specify your headers in `Select-Object -Property` :-)

Comment: H1 H2 H3 H4
Name Type Value Description

Comment: Thats a comment. At the moment I just have the headers in my csv file. How do I search through the file and pick out any values that are in 'Name' field

Comment: Please edit your intial post to add your new code and an example of the json content.

Comment: This is my json file:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201313/discussion-between-patrick-and-hankey39).