# Powershell script to convert JSON variable file to CSV

Tags: json, powershell

I am new to Powershell so please excuse any errors I may have.
I need to write a Powershell script to convert a JSON variable file to CSV.
I need to iterate through the file and pick out all the variables for Name and Id fields.

Firstly I convert the json file to a String.But I am not sure how to iterate through the json file and pick out any of the Name field items. I then export it to a csv file.

This converts the json file to a String

```
$data = (Get-Content "C:\Users\QVL6\Downloads\express-ordering-web- 
variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

This exports it to a csv file:

```
 $data | Select-Object -Name,  Description | Export -Csv -Path .\data.csv 
 -  NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

I need help with a for each loop that will iterate through the file and place any of the Name field values to the csv file under a heading Name.

Below is the first 3 objects of the json file:

```
{
      "Id": "f73bdd3d-0449-036d-c2b6-b5fde280b05f",
      "Name": "CIFolderPermissionGroup",
      "Description": null,
      "Scope": {},
      "IsEditable": true,
      "Prompt": null,
      "Type": "String",
      "IsSensitive": false
    },
    {
      "Id": "f138f849-1647-4346-6ac4-cee4bdbd808a",
      "Name": "CustomInstallFolder",
      "Value": "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot",
      "Description": null,
      "Scope": {},
      "IsEditable": true,
      "Prompt": null,
      "Type": "String",
      "IsSensitive": false
    },
    {
      "Id": "99d478fb-6ef3-cc21-7997-4a9b12f3ad00",
      "Name": "eimasConfiguartion",
      "Value": "{\"issuelocal/":true}",
      "Description": null,
      "Scope": {
        "Environment": [
          "Environments-63"
        ]
    }
```

This is my code so far:
    $json = (Get-Content "C:\Users\QVL6\Downloads\express-ordering-web- 
    variables.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)

```
# helper to turn PSCustomObject into a list of key/value pairs
function Get-ObjectMembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
)
$obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
    $key = $_.Name
    [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
}
```

}

```
#Produce a list of output objects with Name, Type, Value and Description

$ | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-ObjectMembers | foreach {
   $_.Value | Get-ObjectMembers | where Key -match "Name" | foreach {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.value.data.value | select 
            Type = $_.Value.data | value | select 
            Value = $_.Value.data | value | select 
            Description = $_.Value.data | value | select    
        }
    }
}


$path = C:\Users\QVL6\
$data | Select-ObjectMambers -Property Name, Type, Value, Description | 
Export -Csv -Path .\data.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: you can directly use [Convertto-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6) which is much easier to handle your case.

Comment: The code you posted is broken due to incorrect wrapping and your sample JSON data is invalid. Also, you didn't explain what about the code you have doesn't work the way you expected. Examples of desired and actual output might help. Please create a [mcve] and update your question with that.

Comment: I have updated the code above. I am unable to produce a csv file. Could you tell me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: You don't need to give exact data from the CSV - simply show us the headers and give us example data which would match the CSV

Comment: Could you show us how the csv should look like (header and sample rows)?

Comment: Headers:    Name    Type    Value    Description

Comment: Below each header I would like the contents from the json file which match those headers]

Comment: This looks like the same question you were asking in [your previous PowerShell and JSON question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505135/powershell-script-to-get-data-from-json-file). Please explain the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell script to get data from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505135/powershell-script-to-get-data-from-json-file)